# Why does Photoshop list more .icc profiles than Lightroom 5?

Tags: lightroom, soft-proofing

Why are more .icc profiles showing in Photoshop than in Lightroom?

Specifically, I'm trying to soft proof my image to the FOGRA27Coated profile to match the profile used by my printer company. I'm following the very good explanation and instructions at http://www.pixbookdesign.com/FOGRA27.html. The profile exists at:

```
C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\color\CoatedFOGRA27.icc
```

and I can successfully soft proof to this in Photoshop CS6.

But my preferred tool is Adobe Lightroom 5. If I go to the **Develop** module, and click on **Soft Proofing** it only shows some of the profiles, and only defaults to RGB profiles, not to CMYK profiles.

Can I soft proof to FOGRA27 from within Lightroom?

(BTW, the reason I'm doing this is because I was providing the images as RGB to printers and they were converting to FOGRA27 before printing, in most cases this was fine but for some images containing certain blues and greens they did not look right. So, I want to try different mappings to the fogra profile myself (Perceptual, Relative) and provide the printer with the image with an embedded fogra profile instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightroom v.5 can use only RGB profiles because all controls are working either in RGB or through RGB, it does not support CMYK.

If you want to soft-proof to CMYK in Lightroom, try v.6.

Comment: Ah yes I Ive just read it was added in v6

Comment: Confirmed you can softproof to CMYK based profiles in Lightroom 6

Comment: No, the CMYK softproofing is not working properly. First you can't select any CMYK profiles, there's none in the list. You can copy some to the \AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Lightroom\Color Profiles\ folder, but then the simulation still does not work. Also Paper & Ink simulation does not work. Tested in Lightroom CC 2015.9 (Camera Raw 9.9): this is the most recent version now (April 2017). And even worse, the CMYK softproofing was working in previous versions of Lightroom. So thank you guys at Adobe ... :(

Comment: @maravac : For now, it is gone. I'm afraid I do not know how much time it will take Adobe to debug it and put it back.